# Obtain the associated Id for RadRating on RadGrid from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, rad-controls

I'm using Telerik's ASP.NET AJAX libaries and I have a RadRating element for each row in a RadGrid, and need to get the associated Id for the row where the RadRating is being Rated (but with Javascript), however, the `get_parent()` method is returning the grid reference and not the row.

How can I get the `GridDataItem` of the row of the RadRating?

The following code works sometimes but not all the time. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(global,undefined) {

        function OnClientRating(controlRating,args) {
            var row = controlRating.get_parent();
            var userId = row.getDataKeyValue("UserId");
        }

        global.OnClientRating = OnClientRating;

    })(window);
</script>

<rad:RadGrid runat="server" ID="gridUsers" Skin="Hay" 
            EnableAJAX="False"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            GridLines="Both"
            Width="100%"
            AllowSorting="True"
            OnItemDataBound="Grid_ItemDataBound">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="UserId" ClientDataKeyNames="UserId"> 
        <Columns>
            <rad:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="180px" ItemStyle-Width="180px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("FullName")%> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </rad:GridTemplateColumn>
            <rad:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Rating" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <rad:RadRating ID="ratAppraiserRating" runat="server" ItemCount="5" Value='<%# Eval("AverageRating")%>' 
                        SelectionMode="Continuous" Precision="Item" Orientation="Horizontal" OnClientRating="OnClientRating"
                        OnRate="RatRating_Rate" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </rad:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Scrolling UseStaticHeaders="false" ScrollHeight="240px"  AllowScroll="true"  />
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" />
        <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="selectRow" />
    </ClientSettings>
</rad:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `get_parent()` ?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson get_parent() is a method of the RadRating object in Javascript. In fact of every control in Rad controls

Comment: I assure you there is no RadRating object in JavaScript, perhaps you're referring to some framework or API?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson controlRating object passed to the OnClientRating represents the RadRating. it contains the method get_parent(). It is obviously part of the Telerik's library.

Comment: This is not a JavaScript question by nature, I'm trying to tell you that you need to specify the API or Framework you are using, add the appropriate tags to your question, and rephrase what you're asking

Comment: Wasn't it clear when mentioning Telerik in the tags? If it was not clear, I added it as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found. `get_parent()` method does not return the row at all. What I was seeing was red herring. `get_parent` returns the parent control which is the grid, then to find which rows it belongs I found two options:

1) Obtain the HTML element and go through the parent nodes until finding the rows and get the `rowIndex`. And use that index to obtain the respective `DataItem` from the grid.

```
var rowIndex = controlRating.get_element().parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1;
```

2) Subscribe to the `OnRowMouseOver` event of the grid, and keep a reference of the `DataGridItem`, and use it when really needed.

```
var currentDataItem = undefined;

function onRowMouseOver(sender, eventArgs) {
  currentDataItem = eventArgs.get_gridDataItem();
}
```

UPDATE: Telerik people suggest a third option

3)

```
function OnClientRating(sender, args) {


    var parentTableView = sender.get_parent();
    var rowID = $telerik.$(sender.get_element()).closest("tr")[0].id;
    var rowIndex = rowID.split("__")[1];

    var dataItem = parentTableView.get_dataItems()[rowIndex];

    var someCellText = dataItem.get_cell("ColumnUniqueName").innerHTML;

    // add custom logic here

}
```